# A $\Bbb Z$-valued $\Bbb Q$-coefficient polynomial is a $\Bbb Z$-combination of $\binom{x}{k}$s: $q$-analog?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, q-analogs

I am wondering what a $q$-analog of the following should be:

**Proposition**. If $f(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$ is a polynomial for which $f(\Bbb Z)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ (that is, $f(x)$ is an integer for all integers $x$), then $f(x)=\sum_{k\ge0} a_k\binom{x}{k}$ for some integer coefficients $a_k$.

This can be proved with the forward difference operator $\Delta f(x):=f(x+1)-f(x)$. Since $\Delta\binom{x}{k}=\binom{x-1}{k}$, one can solve for the $a_k$ explicitly. In fact, we get a "discrete Taylor series": $f(x)=\sum (\Delta^nf)(0)\binom{x}{k}$ for arbitrary arithmetic functions $f$.

Defining $b_k(x):=\displaystyle \frac{(x-1)(x-q)\cdots(x-q^{k-1})}{(q^k-1)(q^k-q)\cdots(q^k-q^{k-1})}$, we have $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k\end{smallmatrix}\right]_q=b_k(q^n)$. What comes to mind is

**Candidate**. If $f\in\mathbb{F}(q)[x]$ is such that $f(q^n)\in\mathbb{F}[q]$ for all $n=0,1,2,\dots$ then $f(x)=\sum a_k(q)b_k(x)$ for some $a_k\in\mathbb{F}[q]$.

The $q$-derivative $Df(x)=\displaystyle \frac{f(qx)-f(x)}{qx-x}$ seems to give $D b_k(x)=q^{1-k}b_{k-1}(x)$, so the same proof won't work.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{F}[q]$ is the field extension with $q$ as an indeterminate and $\mathbb{F}(q)$ is its field of fractions.

Why wouldn't you define it as $f([n]_q)\in \mathbb{F}[q]$? That seems more analogous to $f(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Of course $\Bbb F[q]$ is ring of polynomials in an indeterminate $q$ and $\Bbb F(q)$ the field of rational functions, over a field $\Bbb F$. @SamJaques Good point. Then you could write $b_k(x)=x(x-[1])\cdots(x-[k-1])/[k]$. Not sure which would be better.